# MySQL - Combine this into one Query in Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Given the following schemas:

```
user
   - id
   - username

friends
   - user_id
   - friend_id

places
   - id
   - name

place_user
   - user_id
   - place_id
```

Users have a ManyToMany Relationship with themselves via the Friends pivot.

Places have a manyToMany relationships with Users via place_user

how do you get all `Places` associated with a `User` AND a `User's Friends`?

Assuming we're working with User 1, in raw SQL, I can get all `Places` associated with that User's `Friends`:

```
Select places.place from places
inner join place_user on place_user.place_id = places.id
inner join friends on friends.friend_id = place_user.user_id
inner join users on users.id = place_user.user_id
where friends.user_id = 1
```

And I can get all `Places` associated with that `User`:

```
Select places.place from places
left join place_user on place_user.place_id = places.id
left join users on users.id = place_user.user_id
where users.id = 1
```

But how can I combine this into one query, and moreover, using Eloquent?

EDIT:  Obviously I could do a Union of these two queries, but I was wondering if there's something more succinct, and perhaps less verbose in Eloquent

Comment: Do you have models for the tables yet?

Comment: Yea I do. Should I post those? They just have the relationship methods

Comment: What are the relationship method's names? what kind of relations are those? oneToOne and oneToMany?

Comment: sure.  just updated the question with that info